# Gnome Terminal Monokai

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization

I am trying to use the **monokai color palette** in my `gnome-terminal` from the following `github` repo : https://github.com/pricco/gnome-terminal-colors-monokai

It worked straight in my latest installation. But under my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS workstation I can't get it to work correctly.

I applied the script overwrite my current profile. It seems that it updated my terminal color palette but not in the right order (folders doesn't get the good color for instance).

I still have my old user folder save. Is there any way to restore my old configuration using `gconf` or `dconf` ?

[image: Gnome terminal color palette]

Here's how it renders in the terminal :

[image]

Comment: What do you want now? Restoring older one or using Monokai?

Comment: Restoring the old one would be better as I think I did some customization, but starting with plain old monokai straight would be nice. I can provide any dotfiles settings if needed

Comment: Could you please be more specific and describe your problem? To me it looks everything's fine. Does the first screenshot show your current (new) gnome-terminal's Preferences window? "not in the right order" - which colors seem to be out of order, what would you expect instead? "folders don't get the good color" - seems to me the exact same shade of mid-blue than on the palette, so again, what is exactly the problem, what else would you expect to see any why?